# SBT: How can I create a utility jar as a post build step to include all dependent jars in a classpath

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am quite new to SBT customization. As a post-build step, I would like to create

1. *Utility* jar which has a class-path that points to all the dependencies.
2. The script created by archetype *JavaAppServerPackaging* should use this *utility* jar rather than including all the dependencies as CLASSPATH.

How can this be done?

I am considering it as an lightweight alternative to creating a fat jar through assembly plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usecase is already covered by two (slightly) different plugins you can enable.

```
enablePlugins(ClasspathJarPlugin)
```

See also the docs for more info:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/longclasspath.html

Cheers,
Muki

Comment: I used 'LauncherJarPlugin' as it was more applicable in my case. The generated script now uses launcher, so everything is good.